# Sticky nav bar: Content not clickable after set z-index

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I implemented a sticky nav bar with the third party library from *yahoo/sticky-node*. At first my code dosen't work and the content with a list of products overlaps the nav bar. After I set the z-index of my products to -1, the nav bar overlaps the products. But now I cannot click the product images, that link to a details page, anymore.

Any solutions for this problem ?

```
const Header = () => {
  const backgroundImage = useHeaderBackgroundQuery()
  const headerText = useHeaderTextQuery()
  const cartIcon = useCartQuery()
  return (
    <div class="shadow-sm mb-5" style={{ width: "100%"}}>
      <Img fluid={backgroundImage} style={{ minHeight: "60px" }} />
      <div
        class="d-flex"
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0",
          height: "100%",
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <div class="p-2">
        <Link to="/">
            <Img fixed={headerText} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto p-2">
          <Link to="/cart">
            <Img fixed={cartIcon} />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const Products = ({ data }) => {
  console.log("products")
  console.log(data.allShopifyProduct)
  return (
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        {data.allShopifyProduct.edges.map(({ node }) => (
          <div class="col-md-4" style={{zIndex: "-1"}}>
            <Link to={`/product/${node.handle}`}>
              <Img
                fluid={node.images[0].localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
                style={{ maxHeight: "350px", maxWidth: "350px" }}
              />
            </Link>
            <div>
              <h5 class="text-center" style={{marginTop: "8px"}}>{node.title}</h5>
              <hr class="mt-2 mb-2" style={{width: "50%", backgroundColor: "black"}}/>
              <p class="text-center font-weight-bold" style={{marginBottom: "20px"}}>
                €{node.priceRange.minVariantPrice.amount}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const ProductsPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      <Sticky>
        <Header />
      </Sticky>
      <Products data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: a z-index of `z-index: -1;` means that it will below the body layerwise. Means also that it is not clickable. just give it a higher z-index then the body (default is 0). Also I see no `position: sticky;` which would not require any z-index in the first place.

Comment: Okay thanks that helps, I set the z-index of my products to 0 and the z-index from my header to 1. Now the content is clickable again and it dosen't overlaps the header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `z-index` to `-1` your content will not be clickable even as body content.
In other words, the body will overlap your content.

So, just put `z-index` to 0 on your content and `z-index` to 1 for nav bar.

**Products**

```js
const Products = ({ data }) => {
  ...
          <div class="col-md-4" style={{ zIndex: '0' }}>
            <Link to={`/product/${node.handle}`}>
              <Img
                fluid={node.images[0].localFile.childImageSharp.fluid}
                style={{ maxHeight: '350px', maxWidth: '350px' }}
              />
            </Link>
            <div>
              <h5 class="text-center" style={{ marginTop: '8px' }}>
                {node.title}
              </h5>
              <hr
                class="mt-2 mb-2"
                style={{ width: '50%', backgroundColor: 'black' }}
              />
              <p
                class="text-center font-weight-bold"
                style={{ marginBottom: '20px' }}
              >
                €{node.priceRange.minVariantPrice.amount}
              </p>
            </div>
            ...
};
```

**Header**

```js
const Header = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <div class="shadow-sm mb-5" style={{ width: "100%", zIndex: '1'}}>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: the Op already got the information as a comment 23 minutes befor you anwsered and stated that the issue was resolved 17 minutes before your anwser. No reason to try to claim free reputation now with something that was already anwsered.

Comment: That's not the case at all. I didnt see the comment at all. Just saw a question that needed answering. No need to point fingers like that

Comment: I claim this answer as accepted, because is the same that i do with the help from @tacoshy